# Выбор строки из таблицы с последующим выводом значений в переменную

Tags: html, jquery, css

На странице есть некоторая таблица(рис1) в которую выводится таблица из базы данных.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Необходимо нажатием на строку сохранить значения со всех колонок и/или передать их в форму для последующего апдейта всей записи.
Собственно как реализовать выбор и передачу переменных из таблички на странице?

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>Орг структура</th>
          <th>Удален?</th>
          <th>Корпус</th>
          <th>Служба</th>
          <th>Подразделение</th>
          <th>Городской</th>
          <th>Новый городской</th>
          <th>Локальный</th>
          <th>Этаж</th>
          <th>Примечание</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><%= row['id'] %></td>
                <td><%= row['OrgStrukture'] %></td>
                <td><%= row['deleted'] %></td>
                <td><%= row['housing'] %></td>
                <td><%= row['service'] %></td>
                <td><%= row['units'] %></td>
                <td><%= row['ph_city'] %></td>
                <td><%= row['ph_cityNew'] %></td>
                <td><%= row['ph_local'] %></td>
                <td><%= row['floor'] %></td>
                <td><%= row['note'] %></td>
                <!-- Тут надо добавить еще колонки -->
              </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Cтили взяты из бутстрапа. <%= .. %> -руби инъекции

> Код всей страницы:https://paste2.org/hmbnmOeX

Comment: в чем конкретно сложность ваша? получить кликнутую строку можете? перебрать все ячейки в ней? сложить это в массив/объект? отправить запрос/или что то еще?

Comment: Ну хотя бы верстку  выложи...

Comment: Сложность в фиксации строки и получении из нее переменных. Верстку приложил

Comment: Куда приложил?...

Comment: @Air в сам вопрос.

Comment: ну допустим мы собрали данные из строки, дальше то что хотите с ними сделать, куда и как передать?

Comment: Желательно сразу передать в поля <input>, которые находятся во всплывающем окне, где отредактируем все что хотим. И апдейтом отправим в БД.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

помечайте ячейки атрибутами, на основании которых поймете, куда и как вставлять данные. Где то надо вставить просто значение, а где-то в таблице у вас будет текст, а вставить нужно будет значение селекта, или флажка и так далее.

Так что либо некоторый объект конфигурации, связывающий номера ячеек и что и как они должны делать. Либо атрибуты к ячейкам.

```js
$("#data").on('click', "tr", function(){
   
   $(this).find("td")
          .each(function(){
               var f = $(this).data('field');
               var v = $(this).data('value');
               
               $("#" + f).val( v == undefined ? $(this).text() : v);
               
            });
          
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>id</th>
        <th>имя</th>
        <th>возарст</th>
        <th>отдел</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data">
      <tr>
         <td data-field="id">1</td>
         <td data-field="name">василий</td>
         <td data-field="age">20</td>
         <td data-field="dep" data-value="1">ИТ</td>
      </tr>
      
<tr>
         <td data-field="id">2</td>
         <td data-field="name">константин</td>
         <td data-field="age">30</td>
         <td data-field="dep" data-value="2">бухгалтерия</td>
      </tr>      
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="row">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <input id="id"   type="hidden" value="">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
       <label>Имя</label>
       <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
       <label>Возраст </label>
       <input id="age"  type="number" class="form-control">
     </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
       <label>Отдел</label>
       <select id="dep" class="form-control">
          <option value="1">ИТ</option>
          <option value="2">бухгалтерия</option>
       </select> 
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```